# Google Maps, Pixel Grid to Lat/Long (?)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For quite some time now I've been trying to get a "game map" into Google Maps. My goal is to have the map being able to zoom etc. (default Google Maps features & done already) and to place markers on it, showing objects from the game. This is where my problem's at.

The game (ArmA) has a variable coordinate system which totally depends on the "world" you're playing in. Let's just say my world has 10200 by 10200 units which can be float, so 5212.123 would be possible.

I have all objects that I want to display on my map stored in a JS array which looks like the following:

```
["class_name",5200,4800]
```

The first one describes the class name or let's just pretend the name of the object, the other two describe the X and the Y value. I banged my head against the wall trying to find some way which enables me to define pixel coordinates on the base zoom level which then change on zooming in / out... but that didn't work out / or rather I didn't find anything on it.

Now I tried converting the coordinates to Lat / Long but I guess Lat / Long aren't constant because it still is not very accurate: I tried dividing the 170 lat units by my 10200 game units and it brought some nice results... but as said: Not very accurate ones.

Is there any way which is some kind of "intelligent, clever or smooth" to do this? Or is Google Maps not the tool for this?

Edit:

Here's how I currently do it...

```
// The game caculates the Y axis from the bottom up, so I turn it around by
// subtracting the coord of the object from the highest possible value
$worldspaceCoords[0] = $worldspaceCoords[0];
$worldspaceCoords[1] = 10200 - $worldspaceCoords[1];

// My lat ranges from -85 to +85 = 170 in total, same goes for the long
// I use 9100 and 9700 because I have calculated offsets in my map
$latCoF = 170 / 9100;
$lonCoF = 360 / 9700;

// Now I calculate lat and long by starting at the min value and going to the max
$worldspaceLatLon['lat'] = 85 - $worldspaceCoords[1] * $latCoF;
$worldspaceLatLon['lon'] = -180 + $worldspaceCoords[0] * $lonCoF;
```

I get the objects via PHP and output them to a  section where they are stored in the array later parsed by the marker creator loop.

This is how they SHOULD look (old map version, not Google Maps)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqJil.jpg)

This is how my results look so far with the code i posted earlier (Google Maps)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2nje.jpg)

Comment: check [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates)

Comment: *but I guess Lat / Long aren't constant because it still is not very accurate* can you explain this? why should Lat/longs not be accurate/constant?

Comment: @Dr.Molle It seems like it. If I calculate 360 for -180 to +180 in long and divide it by 10200 to get the long / per unit it shifts. The first few objects seem quite correct but the next ones drift off more and more.

Comment: @mojzis: I saw this one. But I'm kind of confused when it comes to caculating it the reverse way. I want to insert pixel coords and get lat/lon out of it or I want to insert pixel coords in an absolute way. When I experimented around with pixels I found it odd that my overlay shifted around (at least I could not identify why the pixel coordinates of 0/0 were somewhere completely off my 0/0 lat / lon)

Comment: You can't calculate the LatLng's based on your coordinates without a projection, in your case you'll need to use a [custom projection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#Projections)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Dr.Molle - this is where I'm at now (http://timz-pantheramap.virtu.hiqworks.com/).

The quadrants with the bigger strokes describe 1000x1000 units. The small quadrants describe 100x100 units. If you compare a coordinate on the top left with one on the bottom right you will see they shift... Which is weird.

This is how I calculate it now: I got a projection of 256x256 so I take 256 / 10200 and use this to position the objects. After that I have added some offsets where the map has been cropped. Is something wrong about that?

Comment: I'm not able to load the linked page